# Am I wrong to assert that I was punished with no chance to defend myself?

Tags: punishment, state-university

I received an email from my University stating that I cannot speak to an entire department for the rest of my studies, because I have been sending this department too many emails and phone calls and that I "nearly" breached the Student Code of Conduct.

I alleged that this is in violation of their own policies, because I was not given a chance to defend myself against this punishment. Secondly, the Student Code of Conduct states that a restriction of access to a department must, in the first instance, not exceed 14 days. However, I am more concerned about the argument they are putting forward, specifically, stating that I am not being punished....

My University is arguing that this is not a punishment....I don't even know what to say to that?

Fundamentally, by reducing my agency within the University, they have caused to me a loss. A loss is a fundamental element of a punishment.

Where is my logic going wrong?

Comment: As your quote of the **Student Code of Conduct** clearly states, this is a **restriction** not a punishment.

Comment: There are some gaps in your story. Why did you need to contact the department so many times? Are you sure that this is not "*the first instance*" of prohibiting you to approach the department? Note that a first instance does not need to be as harsh as the permanent one. Also, what specific loss(es) is this prohibition causing you?

Comment: A similar question? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52398/what-can-happen-if-you-violate-a-cease-and-desist-letter/52420#52420

Comment: As this is about internal policies of a university, this may get better answers on Academia, especially if you're looking for practical advice.

Comment: @You'rebadandshouldfeelbad OP has tried to get answers on Academia with multiple questions and variations related to the same incident. It looks like most have been deleted. If I understand correctly, OP would like to go to grad school in that department or possibly elsewhere which makes it more difficult.

Comment: You might want to post this question on https://academia.stackexchange.com/